# How to continue looping through links using "find_elements" after navigating back a page with Selenium in Python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

Building a scraping tool to alphabetically collect names, addresses, and phone numbers from a public phone book (ultimately to export into CSV).

The website allows you to search alphabetically, I'm going through all the last names starting with A, which requires you to click on A. Some last names have 100's of people, so sometimes you may need to loop through multiple pages of the same last name.

The code is below:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

import requests

import time
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException

from openpyxl import Workbook
from openpyxl.utils import get_column_letter


import csv

PATH = '/Users/j_smith/downloads/chromedriver'

driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)

driver.get("https://whitepagescanada.ca/bc/surrey/a-z/A/")    
time.sleep(0.1)


name_elements = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//ul[@class='links-list-alt']")
num_of_name_elements = len(name_elements)
print("Number of elements in the list:", num_of_name_elements)


for name in name_elements:
    time.sleep(0.1)
    name_link = name.find_element_by_tag_name("a").get_attribute("href")
    driver.get(name_link)

    ind_name_elements = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//a[@itemprop='url']")
    print("Number of names: ", len(ind_name_elements))
    for inds in ind_name_elements:
        time.sleep(0.1)

        inds_link = inds.get_attribute("href")
        driver.get(inds_link)
    

        phoneNum_inds = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[@itemprop='telephone']").text
        name_inds = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[@itemprop='name']").text
        address_inds = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[@itemprop='streetAddress']").text

        print("The phone number is:", phoneNum_inds)
        print("The name is:", name_inds)
        print("The address is:", address_inds)

        driver.back()
        time.sleep(0.1)

    driver.get("https://whitepagescanada.ca/bc/surrey/A/")



driver.quit()
```

The code I have is to get the list of names using find_element starting with page 1, then loop through each link of each name on the page, if the name has multiple people then click on each person, gather the info, **navigate back a page**, and then click on the next person with the same last name (iterating on the list through the loop), then **navigate back a page again**, and go on to the next last name (alphabetically still under A) to repeat the steps.

However, I keep getting a "selenium.common.exceptions.StaleElementReferenceException: Message: stale element reference: stale element not found"

I've tried using a WebDriverWait line before each of the find_elements, as well as increasing the time.sleep functions to account for rendering/loading, didn't work...

I understand that by navigating back a page, I need to ensure the correct elements in ind_name_elements are being referenced in inds_link = inds.get_attribute("href"), a bit confused on the best way to execute this.

Please let me know how to best adjust the code to make it work!

Comment: the code is missing the necessary imports for a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Updated - added the imports I had. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and i resolve opening the link in a new tab

```
driver.execute_script("window.open();") # this open a new tab
driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[1]) # this goes to new tab
```

in the new tab driver.get(link), do your thing, and then

```
driver.execute_script("window.close('');") # this close current tab
driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[0]) # this goes back to first tab
```

if you need you can re-use it to open tab #2 and so on

Let me know if it helps